# Select Dropdown option with a value keeps returning null

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, laravel-8

The dropdown below couldn't pass the `required` rule in my validation and kept prompting to select an option, even though I've selected an option already.

```
<div class="col">
    <label for="#">College Degree</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="" id="" name="college_degree" form="" style="margin-top: 1%; border: solid #1ed760; padding: 11px; border-radius: 4px;">
        <option value=" ">Select a Program/Major</option>
        <option value="Associate">Associate</option>
        <option value="Bachelor">Bachelor</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I did a `dd(request()->input('college_degree'));` and turns out `college_degree` returns `null` even with an option selected, which is probably the reason for the validation error.

I inspected the dropdown element with my browser and the option values are correct. None of the option values are empty.  What could be wrong with the dropdown?

Comment: Most likely the `name=""` in there.

Comment: omg, that fixed it. can't believe i didn't notice the duplicate name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

you can try add name="" attr? like name="company"

you use 2 times name="" attribute.

Comment: The select already has the `name="college_degree"` attribute

Comment: I know, but the problem may have been caused by the fact that it was used twice.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).